# can I make an app to automate WhatsApp using python?

Tags: android, python-3.x, automation, kivy, whatsapp

Is there a way to use python and maybe kivy or pyqt to build an app that runs from an android phone that automates WhatsApp. I have seen apps(like automate) on the play store that do it yet I want to do it myself plus most likely those apps aren't built in python. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can use a library made for python to automate WhatsApp and use WhatsApp web or you could pay for a service like Twilio.

Comment: You'll likely have an easier time using python+selenium on web.whatsapp.com

Comment: I already did that With WhatsApp web on pc, I want the control that I had with selenium, only on mobile and the app, not the website since I would have to authenticate on the same phone using WhatsApp. I want to build the app myself so I don't want to use Twilio. I came across a question here with appium but this would require a pc to run and I want to be able to run it without a pc. My first go-to try will be using selenium and chrome for android then try to use it via another phone but the other problem I will be facing is how would I open the same account on different phones.